# how to set the default to NSUserNotificationAlertStyle the Alerts notification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, nsusernotification, nsusernotificationcenter

I am new to iOS.
The app I am working on has in Settings under Notification Center the Alert style set by default to Banners.
I would like to change that to Alerts. How can I do that?
After doing some search on google i found that this should be changed from Info.plist using NSUserNotificationAlertStyle.

I need some help. I don t know how to set this. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That variable is only valid on OSX Apps, not on iOS Apps.

On iOS, the style of the notification is set on the settings of the phone, so the user decides what style he wants for all apps.

Is not possible on iOS to change the style within the app and for just that app.

Check here for confirmation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

Comment: I see. thank you. Is there a link where this subject about ios notification style is written?